# Deploy meanjs into cloud9 IDE

Tags: configuration, cloud9-ide, meanjs

I'm starting to develop with the stack meanjs. I'm using Cloud9 as a cloud IDE (I need its team functionalities). I tried previously to install mean in my local machine successfully. My problem arise when I try to install it in my cloud9 workspace. Does anybody know how to do it? I tried this https://github.com/meanjs/mean/issues/4 but it's not working.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: I added some comments here: https://github.com/meanjs/mean/issues/4 please follow the last one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is just following the steps that I listed in command line. I found the solution from youtube.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RQ1HqBjT890

1. First, you need to utilize mongoDB. Type following:

   ```
   echo "export NODE_PATH=$NODE_PATH:/home/ubuntu/.nvm/v0.10.35/lib/node_modules" >> ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc

   mkdir data

   echo 'mongod --bind_ip=$IP --dbpath=data --nojournal --rest "$@"' > mongod

   chmod a+x mongod

   ./mongod
   ```
2. At this point, your mongoDB server is running. Then, you need to install node package manager, update it. Also, install yo generator.

   ```
   npm install npm -g

   npm update

   npm install -g yo

   npm install -g generator-meanjs
   ```
3. Then, create your project directory, create your mean app.

   ```
   mkdir myMeanProject

   cd myMeanProject

   yo meanjs
   ```
4. Open a new terminal window, and run server.

   ```
   cd myNewProject

   grunt
   ```